# Como pasar tabla a mat-table de angular material

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-material, table

Tengo una tabla dinámica ya que las columnas pueden cambiar o tener links o tener imágenes
puede que una fila tenga algo que otra fila no tenga.

Funciona correctamente la tabla pero quisiera verla ahora con la tabla de angular material, pero no se como pasarla ya que cambia las estructura

trate de hacerla como tengo mi tabla pero me di cuenta que debo agregarlo a un datasource y agregarle todo el arreglo y una variable con las columnas
pero en mi caso al ser dinamico no puedo agregar las columnas enduro
y me da error al querer probar con material

lleno la tabla de la siguiente manera:

html:

```
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th  *ngFor="let item of headers">
                    {{item.value}}
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of filas" class="line">
                  <td  *ngFor="let header of headers">
                    <div [innerHTML]="getValue(item.data,header.key)"></div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

ts:

```
    GenerarTabla(jsonData: any = []): void {
   
    var encabezados = jsonData.map((c: any) => { return ({ key: c.clave, value: c.descripcion }) })
    this.headers = encabezados.filter((obj: any, index: any, self: any) =>
      index === self.findIndex((o: any) => o.key === obj.key && o.value === obj.value)
    );

    this.filas = jsonData.reduce((acumulador: any, objeto: any) => {
      // Comprobar si el grupo ya existe en el acumulador
      const index = acumulador.findIndex((grupo: any) => grupo.id === objeto.id);

      if (index === -1) {
        // Si no existe, agregar un nuevo grupo al acumulador
        acumulador.push({ id: objeto.id, data: [objeto] });
      } else {
        // Si existe, agregar el objeto al grupo correspondiente
        acumulador[index].data.push(objeto);
      }

      return acumulador;
    }, []);

  }

    getValue(json: any[], key: any) {
        let item = json.find(c => c.clave == key);
    
        let value = "";
        let idTipo = item ? item.idTipoCampo : 0;
        switch (idTipo) {
          case 6:
            value = item ? item.valor : "";
            break;
          case 8:
            value = item ? `<a href="${item.valor}" target="_blank">${item.valor}</a>` : '';
            break;
          case 4:
            value = item ? `<img src="Base64:${item.datoBin}"/>` : '';
            break;
          default:
            value = item ? `<p>${item.valor}</p>` : "";
            break;
        }
        return value;
      }
```

data:

```
jsonData = [
    {
      id: 11867468,
      clave: '211',
      descripcion: 'Expediente',
      valor: '121632',
      datoBin: null,
    },
    {
      id: 11867468,
      clave: '112',
      descripcion: 'Registro de Aviso Comercial',
      valor: '113551',
      datoBin: null,
    },
    {
      id: 11867468,
      clave: '211c',
      descripcion: 'Serie del expediente',
      valor: '1985',
      datoBin: null,
    },
    {
      id: 11867468,
      clave: 'notma3',
      descripcion: 'Descripción del oficio',
      valor: 'DECLARACIÓN DE US',
    },
    {
      id: 11867468,
      clave: 'notma2',
      descripcion: 'Número del oficio',
      valor: '20230989469',
      datoBin: null,
    },
    {
      id: 11867468,
      clave: 'notmal',
      descripcion: 'Fecha del oficio',
      valor: '23/06/2023',
      datoBin: null,
    },
    {
      id: 11867468,
      clave: 'notma4',
      descripcion: 'Enlace electrónico',
      valor: 'https://vidoc.impi.gol',
    },
    {
      id: 11867638,
      clave: '211',
      descripcion: 'Expediente',
      valor: '125175',
      datoBin: null,
    },
    {
      id: 11867638,
      clave: '112',
      descripcion: 'Registro de Aviso Comercial',
      valor: '112879',
      datoBin: null,
    },
    {
      id: 11867638,
      clave: '211',
      descripcion: 'Serie del expediente',
      valor: '1985',
      datoBin: null,
    },
    {
      id: 11867638,
      clave: 'notma3',
      descripcion: 'Descripción del oficio',
      valor: 'EL QUE SE INDICA',
      datoBin: null,
    },
    {
      id: 11867638,
      clave: 'notma2',
      descripcion: 'Número del oficio',
      valor: '20230982934',
      datoBin: null,
    },
    {
      id: 11867638,
      clave: 'notmal',
      descripcion: 'Fecha del oficio',
      valor: '22/06/2023',
      datoBin: null,
    },
    {
      id: 11867638,
      clave: 'notma4',
      descripcion: 'Enlace electrónico',
      valor: 'https://vidoc.impi.g',
    },
  ];
```